# Docker install memcached

Tags: php, docker, memcached, php-7, php-5.6

I am trying to install memcached in Dockerfile but I keep getting th same error. Everything was working fine but looks like some layers were cached I and the images was being built with no problems at all. But since I cleared the cache I can't build the image. Here is some of it's content:

```
FROM php:5-apache

RUN apt-get install -y libmemcached11 libmemcachedutil2 build-essential libmemcached-dev libz-dev
RUN pecl install memcached
RUN echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini
```

There are many other things that are installed but as I said everything was working before. The error is that memcached requires php7 to run. I dont know if something has changed in the recent builds of the library but looks like it refuses to work with php5. Here is the error:

```
pecl/memcached requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.30
pecl/memcached can optionally use PHP extension "igbinary" (version >= 2.0)
pecl/memcached can optionally use PHP extension "msgpack" (version >= 2.0)
No valid packages found
install failed
The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install memcached' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: what if you try the `--no-cache` flag when you try to build your image?

Comment: The same error appears. It was working till now because this is an old project and on every new build it used cached layers. But recently I bought a new laptop and when I tried to build an image on it this mistake appeared. Then I tried to build the image on my old machine with the --no-cache option and the result was the same. The cached layers were deleted and now I can't build an image even on it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you. Are you asking if I am trying to use multiple versions of php or you are telling me that it is possible to use multiple versions of php?

Comment: Accidently deleted my comment which was: you can extend the dockerfile and install multiple versions of php if you need it: So for example `FROM: php:5-apache` and than perform manual commands to install other versions using RUN. But I see the problem seems to be the version of memcached so the answer of fzgregor seems the best solution to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The PECL memcached package introduced the dependency on PHP 7 in version 3.0.0. You can still install the 2.x version of that package:

```
FROM php:5-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmemcached11 libmemcachedutil2 build-essential libmemcached-dev libz-dev
RUN pecl install memcached-2.2.0
RUN echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini
```

Comment: I have some other components that require version of php less than 6. For example gearman:
`pecl install gearman`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that but my container keeps restarting every second. Maybe I should search for the log files and try to find the problem.

Comment: The `dockerfile` given in the answer works for me.  Note that I added `apt-get update &&` in front of `apt-get install` to update the apt cache. Without that `apt-get install ...` will fail.